# Editing time for pages in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I've been asked for "development/editing" time for pages analytics to be made available.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: do you mean analytics on how long it takes each page to load, i.e. performance analytics?

Comment: No, sorry @schnippy
What the client is after is the duration the page/not was being edited...

Comment: wait- what? ;) the goal is to track the amount of time an admin user was editing a page? so, track to google analytics the time from when the admin user opened the page to edit it to when they saved it? I've got an idea how to do this but just want to confirm thats the target scenario because, wow.

Comment: haha. yeah i know. pretty ridiculous, isn't it? But yes, that's what the client wants :( @schnippy

Comment: @schnippy +1 for the great comment. I honestly could not stop laughing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - you want to use [Google Analytics custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) for this and a bit of javascript (though will try and make this as Drupaly as possible). For the timer, you can write javascript/jQuery code to start a timer on the window.load() event and then attach it to the submit button on your particular form. Number of examples of javascript timers, I found [this example](http://cfpg.me/post/Simple+JavaScript+Timer/) that looked promising.

Key thing to get this data to your google analytics account is to add a google analytics push event (see documentation above) so your code would look something like this (rough psuedo code)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   function StartTimer() { some timer function ... }

   function StopTimer() { some timer stop function ... return $time; } 

   startTimer();

   $("#id-for-form-submit-button").click(
       $timeValue = StopTimer();
       _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
          1, // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
          'Editor Time', // Category Name. Required Parameter
          $timeValue,  // This value of the custom variable.  Required.
          3  // Sets the scope to page-level.  Optional parameter.
      ]);

});
```

Finally, you need to attach your javascript to your form (the drupaly part). I use this quick code snippet ([from switchbackcms](http://switchbackcms.com/blog/right-way-include-javascript-your-drupal-form)) as a good way to avoid losing the javascript if the user reloads the form:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'form_in_question'){
     $form['some_element']['#after_build'] = array('_load_my_javascript);
   }
}

function _load_my_javascript($element){
    drupal_add_js(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') 
        . '/track_editors.js');
return($element);
}
```